# How to grab data from the script protected site with Excel VBA?

Tags: php, vba, excel

I can't import data table from the site which contain stock data. I did in MS Excel 2007; Data > Get External Data > From Web > Import as usual but there have no return from sites. When I tried to grab data table from the site its shown a small window massage (screenshot), I think the process redirecting to another link; but ultimate result is zero. I think the page is script protected.

Redirecting massage: "Opening: 'http://www.dsebd.org/latest_share_price_all.php"

Please advice me how could I download ( import) data from such site in my Excel Workbook.

The site original link: http://www.dsebd.org/latest_share_price_scroll_l.php [I want to download data from here]

Thanks in Advance for any support.

Comment: I was able to import by clicking the top most left arrow. Tried it from Excel 2010

Comment: I have tried several time with excel 2010 from 'http://www.dsebd.org/latest_share_price_scroll_l.php'; but its failed. :( No result

Comment: did you click the top most left arrow like I mentioned above?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout thanks for your quick reply. But I have tried several time with excel 2010 from 'http://www.dsebd.org/latest_share_price_scroll_l.php'; its failed. :( No result. I want to catch just information of data Table which called "Latest Share Price" from the link.

Comment: Did you see my answer below?

Comment: Yes I click the top left & see your answer but look its failed to capture data from Table "Latest Share Price". want to capture this data table only under the row name "# TRADING CODE LTP*  HIGH  LOW CLOSEP* YCP CHANGE TRADE VALUE (mn) VOLUME"

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am waiting.....

Comment: The problem is you do not know vba so I am not sure the best way to explain how to make this work as I do not want to hand out the code in a platter to you.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Please don't misunderstood me. As I am new but I could learn. If you give a simple guideline in ascending order with your code, Then I am sure I can use the code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not problem with Excel. 
Website is using iframe-->and denying access to request...
Look for site code by pressing F12. Did it ever worked for you before

Comment: yes it worked before, but recently it may added some changes in page so that it not working now :( I SEEK ANY SOLUTION TO GRAB THE DATA TABLE PLEASE

Answer (score 0):

The following code will place each trading code, LTP, change and % change on a separate line in the active worksheet.

' open IE, navigate to the website of interest and loop until fully loaded

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://www.dsebd.org/latest_share_price_scroll_l.php"
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 530
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 400

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End With
```

If you use F12 to look at the source code, you'll notice that each stock and it's associated data is bracketed by a tagname (in this case "a"). Use this to collect the data for each stock and place the data for all stocks in "Results".  Step through "Results" and place each stock on a separate line.  Use the replace function to remove a line break so the data appears on 1 line.

```
Set Results = IE.document.getElementsByTagname("table")(0).getElementsByTagname("a")
x = Results.Length

For y = 0 To x - 1
    gg = Results(y).innertext
    gg = Replace(gg, Chr(10), "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
    ActiveCell = gg
    ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select
Next
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Please don't be irritated. I am new in programing concept as well as VBA. If you could please make an easy elaboration of your solution, then it will be helpful for me.

Comment: I added some explanation within my original answer.  I've also noticed that if you click on different licks on the webpage (like Latest Share Price "By Volume") you can use this same technique to collect additional data (like volume) if you need it.

Comment: Please I need an instruction, How could I use these code or apply in my worksheet? As I previously said you I am completely new in programing concept. Please don't be angry on me :(

Comment: just insert a module in your workbook and place this code in a subroutine

Comment: Sorry I failed to use these code. :( I frankly spoke I don't know how to use VBA code in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Press A1 cell, then data-> http://www.dsebd.org/latest_share_price_scroll_l.php-> click first arrow-> import->ok  .....eureka
on cell E1 you will see ur desired thing